# Synchronizing Git Repo with origin SVN repository: Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history

Tags: git, svn, synchronization, rebase

I experience the following error when synchronizing my new `Git` repository cloned from `SVN`. I know that there are a lot of posts regarding that topic and of course i have read them, but none seem matching to my situation:

*Scenario:*
I have to migrate a big projects `SVN` repository with history to `Git`. For a small period the old `SVN` repository is used further, while the new `Git` repository has to synchronized (one way svn -> git) till we finally switch to `GIT`.

*Migration steps:*

```
# checkout svn repo to extract info
svn co svn://host_of_svn_repo/svn_repo_name
# extract author info
svn log -q | awk -F '|' '/^r/ {sub("^ ", "", $2); sub(" $", "", $2); print $2" = "$2" <"$2">"}' | sort -u > authors-transform.txt
# migrate svn repo to git
git svn clone svn://host_of_svn_repo/svn_repo_name --no-metadata -A authors-transform.txt --stdlayout ../my_new_git_repo
cd ../my_new_git_repo
# look for needed branches to migrate
git branch -av
# [-> foreach] branch to migrate, checkout
git checkout -b branchname-svn remotes/branchname
# configure new git remote repository
git remote add origin http://git_repo_host/git_repos_name
# push master branch
git push -u origin master
# [-> foreach] branch to migrate, push it
git push origin branchname
```

Now the origin `SVN` repository gets a new commit, so i want to sync my new  `Git` repository like this:

```
git svn fetch
```

results in something like

```
     A            images/a_new_image.png
r4445  = 12412464563574736573486dgtwsegt7324 (refs/remotes/trunk)
```

Then to complete i want to rebase:

```
git svn rebase
```

and I run in the  following error:

```
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately not. I think this problem is related to git-svn, but i gave up to follow this way. Finally we just migrate all SVN repositroies including all branches to GIT and stopped using SVN anymore, so any synchronizing between GIT and SVN was never necessary. Thats what i would recommend no, because its safe to use, synchronizing between GIT and SVN doesn't seem to be a proper solution for productive use.